# How to compare price using laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I am facing one big problem. The problem is I am passing two prices. According to this two prices get data from table for that I am use `whereBetween` but this is not working. I stuck here and not getting proper solutions from any where. I [ask one some time before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206914/laravel-5-2-wherebetween-not-working) but still not getting any response. Please suggest me.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Both of question's ask by me but on that question didn't get any reply.

Comment: @KrisRoofe I agree with you but I don't have any option for that so I ask question, You have answer please give me. Because it is very very important for me.

Comment: Can you please provide the full query you are using incase its not exactly the same as your old question?

Comment: @Birdy laravel eloquent query is same but now my price column datatype is varchar to integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 whereBetween not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206914/laravel-5-2-wherebetween-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I've checked you original question and you said column type is `varchar`. Change data type for the price column from `varchar` to `integer` and it will work.